# Migration from wildfly8 to wildfly10 with backward compatibility

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly-8, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I faced with a such error during deploying my ear on wildfly 10:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type SomeServices with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject someotherpackage.someService
  at someotherpackage.someService(SomeClass.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Managed Bean [class mypackage.SomeServices] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class mypackage.SomeServices] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

- Managed Bean [class mypackage.SomeServices] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

The cause: mypackage.SomeServices has 2 locations (in wildfly/modules and inside EAR file).

I could set scope to provided and deploy my EAR on wildfly 10 successfully. But in this case it wouldn't work on wildfly 8. How can I do compatibility between wildfly 8 and wildfly 10? I want that wildfly 8 could inject SomeServices from wildfly/modules.